# Factory to create databaseinteractions

Tags: c#, database

I've written a DLL for accessing databases. Therefor I have an Interface called *IDbInterop* which looks like:

```
public interface IDbInterop
    {
        void ExecuteCommandNonQuery(string commandText, params IDbParameter[] commandParameter);
        object ExecuteCommandScalar(string commandText, params IDbParameter[] commandParameter);
        DataSet ExecuteCommandDataSet(string commandText, params IDbParameter[] commandParameter);
    }
```

To get an instance of this Interface for a spezific databaseprovider, i've introduced a Factory which takes an enum as parameter to decide which concrete implementation should be created:

```
public static class DbInteropFactory
{
    public static IDbInterop BuildDbInterop(DbType dbType, string connectionString)
    {
        switch (dbType)
        {
            case DbType.MSSQL:
                return new MSSQLDbInterop(connectionString);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("dbType");
        }
    }
}

public enum DbType
{
    MSSQL,
}
```

I've only implemented a concret implementation for MSSQL databases so far. Now if another databaseprovider should be added I'll have to do the following steps:

- Create a class (e.g. MySqlDbInterop) for the concrete implementation
- Extend the enum (e.g. MYSQL)
- Extend the factory to allow the user to get the new implementation

Is there a way, that I don't have to extend the enum and the factory if a new implementation is added?

Comment: Seems to me you're trying to re-invent the wheel. Use Entity Framework instead.

Comment: Use something like nInject for Dependency Injection?  That's the generic solution to this kind of problem.

Comment: What does your solution give you that the .NET DbProviderFactory class doesn't?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, atleast there are three ways which I am aware of.

1. You can use `Reflection` to instantiate concrete classes but you may have to deal with any performance issues.
2. You can let the concrete classes register themselves with the factory but you need to ensure the registration takes place before any client requests for its instance.
3. You can use any of the available [IoC containers](http://springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html) which uses Dependency Injection (Constructor or Setter Injection) principle to instantiate the concrete class for you. These IoC containers internally may again make use of `Reflection` as stated in the first point.

Comment: I've done it with a static constructor in the factory. in this constructor i iterate through all classes and search for the interface. the interface defines a ReadOnlyProperty to get it't DbType. This Values I write in a static Dictionary. Now I can ask the Factory to get a interface-object for the give DbType

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. Use factory workers. A worker creates an instance and has the knowledge of matching the parameters.

```
public interface IFactoryWorker
{
   IDbInterop CreateInterop( string connectionString );
   bool AcceptParameters( string ProviderName );
}
```

An example worker would be

```
public class SqlServerFactoryWorker : IFactoryWorker
{
    public IDbInterop CreateInterop( string connectionString )
    {
      return new MSSQLDbInterop(connectionString);       
    }

    public bool AcceptParameters( string providerName )
    {
       return providerName == "System.Data.SqlClient";
    }
}
```

Then your factory becomes

```
public static class DbInteropFactory
{
  private static List<IFactoryWorker> _workers;

  static DbInteropFactory()
  {
      _workers = new List<IFactoryWorker>();
      _workers.Add( new SqlServerFactoryWorker() );
  }

  public static void AddWorker( IFactoryWorker worker )
  {
      _workers.Add( worker );
  }

  public static IDbInterop BuildDbInterop( 
     string ProviderName, string connectionString)
  {
     foreach ( var worker in _workers )
     {
        if ( worker.AcceptParameters( ProviderName ) )
           return worker.CreateInterop( connectionString );

        // or return null 
        throw new ArgumentException();
     }
  }
```

This approach has following benefits:

- having string as the provider type means that you don't have to extend any enums
- having workers outside of the factory means that you will never have to change the factory itself
- creating a new provider means that you create a new worker and register it in the factory, this can be done outside of the factory with the `AddWorker` method

This approach follows the Open-Closed Principle.

To simplify the code you could make workers actual interop providers. This means that the worker interface should inherit from `IDbInterop` and implement all the logic. In this approach, the factory tries to locate the "worker-provider" (`foreach ( var worker in _workers`) and just returns it when found:

```
public interface IFactoryWorker : IDbInterop
{
   IDbInterop CreateInterop( string connectionString );
   bool AcceptParameters( string ProviderName );
}

     ...
     foreach ( var worker in _workers )
     {
        if ( worker.AcceptParameters( ProviderName ) )
           return worker;

        // or return null 
        throw new ArgumentException();
     }
```

This comes with the cost of violating the Single Responsibility Principle.